# Define sort order when updating

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have a script that updates an ID field on one table where that record matches to another table based on criteria.

Below is the general structure of my query.

```
update p.saleId = e.saleId
from products p inner join sales s on s.crit1 = p.crit1
where p.someDate between s.startDate and s.endDate
```

This is working fine.  My issue is that in some situations there is more than one match on the 'sales' table with this query which is generally ok.  I'd however like to sort these results based on another field to make sure the saleId I get is the one with the highest cost.

Is that possible?

Comment: can you sent sample data. and output example.

Comment: Is the above update syntax is correct .........?? I think `SET` is missing and you can achieve what you want by using sub query. AND one more thing `e.saleId` where e table or alias is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Sorry yeah wrong syntax, the above is just a representation of what i'm doing as trying to explain the underlying data would be too difficult and unrelated to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers worked, but I managed to do it by using and `Outer Apply` as my join, and specified the sort order in that.

Cheers everyone for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below query may solve. Wrote very high level draft as per your question. Please take only the concept not the syntax.

```
with maxSales as (select salesId, crit1 from sales s1
        where cost = (select max(cost) from 
        sales s2 where s1.crit1 = s2.crit1)     
update products p set p.saleId = 
                 (select s.saleId from 
                   maxSales s
                   where s.crit1 = p.crit1
                   and p.someDate between s.startDate and s.endDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is the `saleID` you want to set and the `sales` table you are looking up, you can probably just update all `products` records. Then you can write a simple update statement on the table and don't have to join. This makes this much easier to write:

```
update products p
set saleId =
(
  select top(1) s.saleId
  from sales s
  where s.crit1 = p.crit1
    and p.someDate between s.startDate and s.endDate
  order by cost desc
);
```

The main difference to your statement is that mine sets saleId = NULL where there is no match in the `sales` table, while your lets these untouched. But I guess that doesn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:**

```
UPDATE p
SET p.saleid = s.saleid
FROM products p
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT s.crit1,
          s.saleid
   FROM sales s
   WHERE cost IN
       (SELECT max(cost) cost
        FROM sales
        GROUP BY crit1)) s ON s.crit1 = p.crit1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE p 
   set p.saleId = e.rowNumber  
FROM products p
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT saleId, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY saleId DESC) as rowNumber
FROM sales) 
e ON e.saleId = p.saleId
```

Comment: I've said to you before and I'll say it again. You're using the snippet tool wrong. It's intended to be used for HTML/JS/CSS that are *actually runnable* on this website. Not for all code.

Comment: Please let me know How use Like  @GrabNewTech ans post

Comment: When you're including code (but not, specifically, HTML/JS/CSS), highlight the code and use the code tool (looks like `{}`). When you're including HTML/JS/CSS, use the snippet tool (looks like `<>` on a page). When you're just including narrative text, use neither.